# Bootstrap d-flex layout

Tags: layout, bootstrap-5, sidebar

Still a novice and learning Bootstrap's [Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) utilities and layout. Trying to utilize Bootstrap's .d-flex, .flex-row, and .flex-column to create a fixed-left Sidebar and the main content on the right-side of the page. Some requirements I need are:

1. Sidebar remains fixed in-place. I do not want it scrolling with the main content.
2. Main content needs to be horizontally-centered in it's flex-column window.
3. I want to be able to make my main content a template where I can use different layout in place. For example, I would like to make one page have just a search form that is vertically-centered as well with a footer at the bottom, and another webpage would have a lot of content that is not centered.

I almost having a working solution and this might be an easy fix; however, my layout for the main content is not responding like I thought. I am trying to create the example that has a vertically-centered search form with a footer placed at the bottom - I can make one of two of those requirements work but not both. I am aware of the issues on using .justify-content-center with an over-flowing flex container where the class will center the content and you can't scroll to the top, but I shouldn't have that scenario for this example.

- [Vertically-centered example](https://codeply.com/v/WFXLjAaiY8): Here I use .justify-content-center with my .flex-column. This centers my search form but my footer wants to be placed right below it. I tried to add a .mb-auto to my search form wrapped in a .flex-column but it seems like it is getting ignored.
- [Footer placed correctly](https://codeply.com/v/EDFm2PuFkt): I can place my footer correctly here but my search form is not placed at the top.

Something else I wanted to ask as a design consideration: should I wrap my search form inside a .flex-column or is there a better approach? It seemed like this method or a .row and a .column combination was the only way I could make it centered with my title.

Thanks for the help.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to @graham_reynolds, I was able to achieve the layout I was after. I have stumbled upon another issue now with my Sidebar; however, when the display is very short and the menu items need to scroll to display all of them. In these scenarios, I thought I needed to add the attribute

`overflow-y: scroll;`

to my custom-CSS file I was using to make my Sidebar. Here is where the problem is...

When I use this attribute and click the "Login" button, my login window *hides* behind my main content on the right side (seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3ToE.png)). So my main question is, how do I avoid this? I thought specifying the overflow in the "y" axis would prevent the content from going from side-to-side.

Currently to avoid this, I just comment out the `overflow-y: scroll;`, but then I get weird behavior on my Sidebar when my display is very short and you scroll down. Here are my two working examples:

- [Sidebar scrolls](https://codeply.com/v/WFXLjAaiY8) but hides my login menu.
- [Sidebar fixed](https://codeply.com/v/EDFm2PuFkt) and get weird behavior.

Here is where I add my overflow attribute in my CSS file

```
.sidebar {
  background-color: #adb5bd;
  min-width: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using your second option add mt-auto to your container fluid:

```html
<main class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 overflow-auto" style="min-width: 700px;">
      <div class="container-fluid mt-auto">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <h1 class="display-3 text-center">
            Circuits
          </h1>
          <form class="loading align-self-center" action="/search/" method="get">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

That will work for your current design.

> Something else I wanted to ask as a design consideration: should I
> wrap my search form inside a .flex-column or is there a better
> approach? It seemed like this method or a .row and a .column
> combination was the only way I could make it centered with my title.

Your layout should follow the bootstrap hierarchy, container -> row -> column. Obviously it does work here where you have columns inside columns, but it is not ideal.

EDIT: You can see this when you go down to mobile, your site is only responsive down to about 800px wide.

Comment: Thank you @graham! I have updated my question based on your suggestion with a new issue I am running into now.